# multi touch problems android

Tags: android, button, multi-touch

i have a project that is supporting multi touch. When you touches a button it passes 1. However, it only gets the first touch . pls help me, it is for our thesis.

here is my code:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     int action = event.getActionMasked();
     if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

       b1=b2=b3=b4=b5=b6="0";

        switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button3:
               b3 = "1";
               break;
           case R.id.button2:
                b2 = "1";
                break;
           case R.id.button1:
               b1 = "1";
               break;
           case R.id.button4:
               b4 = "1"; 
               break;
           case R.id.button5:
               b5 = "1";
               break;
           case R.id.button6:
               b6 = "1";   

        }
     }  else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN )
     { 
         switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button3:
               b3 = "1";
               break;
           case R.id.button2:
                b2 = "1";
                break;
           case R.id.button1:
               b1 = "1";
               break;
           case R.id.button4:
               b4 = "1"; 
               break;
           case R.id.button5:
               b5 = "1";
               break;
           case R.id.button6:
               b6 = "1";   

        }
    }
  }
```

in here when the button1 and button2 is pressed it should pass b1=1 and b2=1 however it only passes the b1=1.

Comment: Do you attach this listener to all buttons, right? Also, seems return statement is missed in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Return `true` to indicate you handled the touch event.

Also, using strings (`b1` through `b6`) as booleans is a patently bad idea. Use a `boolean` instead.

Comment: Be wary of returning `true` just for kicks in a touch listener.  If those views are truly buttons, this will override their ability to be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your touch listener (assuming that all buttons are calling into the same method) is that it resets the values each time you come into the method, and `onTouch()` will get called once for each event you need to process.  In your example where you touch two unique buttons passing through the same listener, the method will be called once with an `ACTION_DOWN` event for the first button you touch, and then a second time with an `ACTION_DOWN` event for the second button you touch.  Your second run through the method resets the values of all `bx` inputs back to zero before setting the value associated with that view, so this code will always only leave one button "marked" as touched.

You might consider resetting the "mark" state on the `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL` events for that view instead to keep a better global state.  I would also agree with other posters that storing these values as strings seems quite inefficient and will make comparison logic more difficult later on.